# Function App (premium) access restrictions and NSG outbound rules

Tags: azure-functions

Two questions on Function App (premium) VNET integration.

When securing the the Function App via Access Restrictions are there service tags that must be configured in order that the function app remains healthy? There is plenty of documentation suggesting the AppServiceManagement service tag should be allowed, but it remains unclear that it is actually required for a Function App.

Similarly for outbound NSG rules, allowing the Storage and AzureMonitor service tags is necessary, but what is the implication of denying the default AllowNetOutbound and AllowInternetOutbound rules?